# Custom resolution on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, resolution

I have never used a raspberry before, and I am having trouble configuring it. I've been searching for an answer to my problem but I have had no success in finding it. Maybe the answer is there but I have not been able to understand it, which is possible.

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 that outputs on a very tall LED wall. It's supposed to show some dynamic content working under HTML5. The code works correctly, as I have tested it on a regular screen with success.

The problem comes when I connect the raspberry to the LED wall. It has a very specific resolution (192 px wide, for 1216 px tall)

Tampering with the configuration, I have set the resolution to the highest I can find, but I'm a few pixels shy of 1216, and with LEDs that big it's very noticeable.

As far as I have found, there is only a limited list of resolutions to choose from. Is there any way to set a manual resolution to 192x1216? Or at least a bigger resolution that my screen fits in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 1216 pixels in height is a little unconventional, I would suggest rotating the screen 90 degrees and setting the resolution to 1216x192 instead.

Add these 2 lines to `/boot/config.txt` and comment out any other occurrences of them if they already exists. You can edit the file by writing `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`

```
display_rotate=1 # Rotate the screen 90 degrees
hdmi_cvt 1216 192 60 # Set the resolution to 1216x192
```

And then reboot the unit with `sudo reboot`

In case the custom resolution doesn't work you could try to work with rotating the screen with the first line and use 1280x720 pixels instead.

Comment: I can't test it now, and won't be able to test it in a few days, past the bounty end-date. Your answer seems promising though, that's why I will reward you the bounty, and I will comment back and accept it as the answer when I'm able to really test it . Thanks

Comment: Cheers, please do come back if it doesn't work so I can see if there's any other solution that could work out.

Comment: It did work. It took a bit of work as it wasn't just applying this and fire, but it worked. I had to set it to 1280x720 since it didn't accept my super-narrow resolution. Sorry for the late response, I'm still struggling with the project for other reasons that's why it took so long.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. I thought it could be a problem with the width of 192px, but I guessed as long as you could fit the height, it would be possible to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

This particular combination of parameters for `/boot/config.txt` was the one that worked for me:

```
disable_overscan = 1
hdmi_group = 2
hdmi_mode = 87
hdmi_cvt = 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
display_hdmi_rotate = 3
```